# Why does lambda expression's argument contain object?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I defined a lambda expression in a class and I'm referring an instance variable (field) from that same class.

```
public class TestLambda {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    {
        name = "Test";
    }

    public void performTasks(int value){
        Consumer<String> consumer = str ->{
            name = "Rest";
            System.out.println(value);
        };
        consumer.accept("randomString"); //DEBUG_HERE
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestLambda testLambda = new TestLambda();
        testLambda.performTasks(5);
    }
}
```

When I debug in the DEBUG_HERE line, I get the consumer object with two arguments
[image]

arg$2 is the local variable that I pass from the main method.
The lambda expression refers to **name** which is an instance variable.
Why is arg$1 a TestLambda (TestLambda@632) type?
Shouldn't it be just the **name** ?

Comment: I get that, but when I remove the line name = "Rest"; I only get one argument. Since it is an inner class, shouldn't the id and the name still be visible?

Comment: There is no such thing as an “inner class” in the JVM. An inner class is implemented as a class having an implicit reference to its outer object, typically named `this$0` or such alike. In that regard, the class generated at runtime for a lambda expression is *not* an inner class. It only has a reference to its outer object when needed. And in that case, the captured reference has a name like any other captured value, e.g. `arg$1`. Since your lambda expression assigns a field of the outer object, it needs a reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions get turned into anonymous classes at compile time. So knowing this, your code should actually look something like:

```
public class TestLambda {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    {
        name = "Test";
    }

    public void performTasks(int value){
        Consumer<String> consumer = new Consumer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(String str) {
                name = "Rest";
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        };
        consumer.accept("randomString"); //DEBUG_HERE
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestLambda testLambda = new TestLambda();
        testLambda.performTasks(5);
    }
}
```

Debugging in the same spot now would get you:
[image: Consumer]

Since this is an anonymous class, it's easier to understand why it has access to the entire parent object.

But lets go further, lets assume the compiler wants to optimise as much as possible. Just passing a String there wouldn't do what you expect due to how parameters are passed in JAVA and the fact that String is immutable.

So this code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "old";
        test(input);
        System.out.println(input);
    }

    public static void test(String a) {
        a = "new";
    }
```

Would print "old"

Comment: the string does change though, if you print testLamba.name after we call performTasks, we get "Rest" and not "Test".

Comment: Yes, it changes *because* the entire object is a parameter and not just the name. That was your question, right? Why don't you only have "name" as a parameter but the entire object.
In the first part I made the case with anonymous inner classes that have access to the entire object by default. And in the second part I explained that you actually don't want just the name as a parameter if you intend to change its value.